# MarkLogic - getting distinct values

Tags: marklogic

I have a database containing XML documents that look roughly as such:

```
<document>
  <question_item>
    <question>What is your name?</question>
  </question_item>
  <question_item>
    <question>What is your address?</question>
  </question_item>
...
</document>
```

I want to be able to take a search term and then return a distinct list of questions where that term is found e.g. searching for "name" with the data above, would return one result, "What is your name?".

I have successfully implemented this with `fn:distinct-values`, but obviously this is not efficient.

I want to implement this with CTS. I have tried the following:

```
for $question in cts:element-values(
  xs:QName('question'),(),(), 
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("question"), "name"))
return $question
```

However this causes questions to come back that do not have "name" in the question text. e.g. in the example above, both questions are returned. I think this is because the query I am using is being passed unfiltered and therefore it is returning any questions from a fragment if there is a match on that fragment.

Is this assumption correct?

What can I do to achieve what I want to do - efficiently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That's correct; `cts:element-values()` is a lexicon-type function, so it runs unfiltered.

The most efficient way to do this is probably to use a matching lexicon function like `cts:element-value-match`:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName('question'), "* name*")
```

The catch is that this uses range indexes directly to do the matching, which don't have some of the features of `cts:search`-based queries, like linguistic stemming, but are the fastest. So for example, to handle all the cases where you might want to match "name", you might have to build a more elaborate set of queries:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName('question'), ("* name?", "name *", "* name *"))
```

If the limitations of wildcards don't present any problems to your application, then this is the most efficient way to query those values, given the structure of your documents.

One compromise solution that still uses `cts:queries` and may be fast enough for your purposes is to filter the values after querying them:

```
for $v in cts:element-values(xs:QName('question'), (), (),
  cts:element-word-query(xs:QName('question'), 'name'))
where cts:contains($v, cts:word-query('name'))
return $v
```

Comment: Thanks wst, really helpful. Weirdly the second (compromise) query you provided is much faster(10x) than the first one. Any idea why that would be? That said I am very happy that the second one is fast.

Comment: @Robert Even on a memory-mapped range index, wildcards (especially leading wildcards) are somewhat expensive. Since you don't need those in the "universal index"-based query, it looks like in your application the cost to wildcard is higher than the cost to filter. The scales might tip the other direction if you have 10-100x the number of documents and/or documents with many more false positives that would need to be filtered. Basically, the size, volume, and structure of your documents can have a big impact on what type of query will be the fastest.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a distinct list of questions now and am able to use cts:frequency to order the questions by how often they occur. 

There is also a <answer> element under each <question_item> to go with each <question>. I would love to be able to show the top 3 answers, when each distinct question text is returned.

Is there any way I could do this efficiently?

Is this where I need to look at storing the documents as question_item as another poster has suggested?

Comment: @Robert Yes, it's possible (with more elaborate filtering) but you should probably create a new question so there's room for a complete answer. Also, WRT grtjn's answer, yes - my answer assumes you want to keep your data structure in tact. But you wouldn't have to get as clever to write fast queries if you can change the structure of your data like he suggests. I would recommend that, if possible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll create a separate question. BTW on the creating separate document structures. Is it a common pattern to take data and store it in two formats e.g. keep my current documen, use a separate collection for each doc structure and then query the collection that most makes sense for the search you are doing? I appreciate this data duplication means extra disk space, and extra work needed to keep data in synch if updated. Just curious if this is a common tactic or a terrible idea. Perhaps it is it better to use something like modular docs?

Comment: This is actually worth a separate question, but to answer: I'd avoid keeping duplicate data, unless there is a clear need for it from user functionality perspective. You could also consider using xinclude to always be able to reconstruct a doc with all questions, for export purposes for instance..

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered saving each `question_item` in a separate file? That way you would not need filtering, and you could run your code unchanged.

HTH!